# Has “call on someone” meaning “pay a short visit” fallen out of usage?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiom-meaning

It would appear that the usage of ***[call on someone](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/call-on)*** meaning  to visit someone, usually for a short time, as in 
“*We could call on my parents if we have time*” has become somewhat obsolete according to this [post on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154217/can-call-on-mean-pay-a-short-visit-to-someone).

The idiomatic expression is well present in  [main dictionaries](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&q=call%20on%20meaning&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC1rnWhubYAhVEvRQKHem5AhYQBQggKAA&biw=768&bih=909) and 
 in the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call_on), for instance it is cited as the first meaning:

> (1)Pay a visit to (someone):
>
> - ‘he's planning to call on Katherine today’

while the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call-on-someone) (3rd entry) defines the expression as an AmE one:

> call on someone (phrasal verb with call US ​) 
>    to come to see someone; visit:
>
> - She went to the hospital to call on a sick friend.

So, is this  expression  still used and commonly understood or is it actually “dated”? or is it more a question of AmE vs BrE usage?

***Edit***:

After I posted this question   a new answer, (actually a wiki answer) has been posted on the ELL question which appears to contradict the main   accepted one. Hope someone can offer  a more conclusive answer to this question, if possible.

Comment: It's still current in British English, though "call *in* on" might be more common.

Comment: Doesn’t feel dated to me either. _Go see_ would probably be more frequent, and _call on_ may be a tad more formal and less colloquial, but I wouldn’t think twice about using it, and I doubt anyone would be considered old-fashioned for doing so either.

Comment: My feeling is that it is on the decline in the US, and tends to be used more for quick, non-social stops, as in *call in at the cleaners and pick up the laundry.* It's decline probably just reflects changes in social behavior stemming from cell phones. You can certainly still call in on aunt Martha at the nursing home and see how she's doing.

Comment: In the Cambridge Dictionary, it's the *meaning* of  `(ASK TO DO)` that is American, the meaning that you cite does not specifically say it is AmEng. See the BrEng variant [call on somebody](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call-on-upon-sb?q=call+on%2Fupon+sb)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You have to look at the 3rd entry   (visit) in the link of Cambridge Dictionary I posted.

Comment: I think you're reading far, far too much into Dan's misunderstanding of a language not his own.

I've only been listening for 60 years but I can't even imagine any native speaker failing to follow that…

Comment: Come on, people; To** call on** meaning to visit is ***old fashioned***, and was used extensively in former times, think horse and carriage. Today, to call on would only be used by people who read and somewhat tongue in cheek.  Today, the Brits are always popping in and over and their cousins (Americans) are coming by or stopping by.

Comment: @Lambie - it appears to be a controversial issue whether it is dated or not as you can see from comments and answers. It might be  a regional issue also with the same country.

Comment: @user159691 Right, well, I realized that call on probably originated with "calling cards" and the practice of making or paying (social) calls: https://hobancards.com/calling-cards-and-visiting-cards-brief-history These cards started at the end of the 18th century right through the 19th century. The people who carried them were called "callers". And the action was to call on someone. I should probably post an answer. I assume usage evolved from that...,.

Comment: @Lambie - that’s an interesting finding and a good point to start considering its usage nowadays.

Comment: A 'conclusive' answer implies that the question should have been frozen after a few weeks, or that English is static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sales currently, we certainly use the term, and it isn't a dated phrase (for us, at least). I also don't see a lot of regional (US) variation for this usage, in my experience.

This an example of the common usage I am referring to:

- "Bill isn't here, he's **calling-on** customers."
- "I usually **call-on** customers in the morning."
- "Yesterday. I **called-on** 18 customers!

Although the hyphen is optional, I usually opt to use it because it tells the reader *these two words are meant to be said and understood together*.

With that said, my blue-collar relatives born in the early 20th Century would use the term. I know doctor's **call-on** their patients in-hospital everyday.

But, I do not use it in social context, I'd instead say "visit" or "go over to" Sue's house.

So, as to the original question, my humble opinion is **call-on** *is still used and commonly understood; however, in SOME areas (e.g., social), it **is** becoming “dated” rather than archaic. In professional areas, its usage seems **alive and well**."*

YOU are rather experiencing the gradual morphing of language over time.  The older you get, the more obvious the words and usage changes become.

Answer (score 3):

In AmE it's pretty obscure. It may be due to the fact that while we used to 'make a *telephone call*', now we simply use ***'call'*** to mean: 'speak via the telephone'. In BrE they say *"ring"*, so the meaning of *call* as "visit" was not trampled on.

Comment: In BrEng the noun "phone call" is very common

Comment: I agree. In the Midwestern US, I'm not sure I've ever heard anyone use "call" to mean "visit" in casual speech (though I'm certainly familiar with the usage from books). The phrase "call on" would probably be understood, but expressions like "make some calls" or "call (a)round" (which I think can refer to in-person interactions in BrE) would universally be understood as referring to phone conversations in the US.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't doubt it. But, in AmE we have abandoned the *"phone"* qualifier, for the most part. As in: "I need to *call* my mother," "Where the hell have you been - you couldn't *call*?" or, "I gotta *call* in to work, to *call* out, today."

Comment: @Oldbag - In BrE we would also say "I need to call my mother". PJ and Duncan (who I'm relatively sure never made it big in the US) had a song in the 90s with the lyric "If I give you my number, will you call?". We don't use "ring" that often. I might "ring" a number, but I'm far more likely to "call" a person.

Comment: Your reasoning that "call" can't mean "visit" seems completely unjustified, especially as a) many words have multiple meanings in english and b) "call on" is differentiated from "call" by the word "on".

Comment: @AndyT -  I didn't say *"can't"* -  I said it's *"obscure"*.

Comment: I suggest it's not at all obscure in US American English, for the simple reason that you first need to choose your M.A.S.H. character before you start specifying anything about 'American English.'

Sure, Klinger prolly won't like it too much and are you really suggesting Winchester won't?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Care to turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: @ aparente001 thanks but don't you think I'd then have to do some research? Either way, everyone I know's been using "If we're going to Wheresit, let's call on/call in on Uncle Fred on the way…" for as long as I can remember.

Comment: ***Obscure is simply not the right word***. It is merely old-fashioned. Anyway, the Brits don't use it much either anymore. They say pop: pop in, pop round, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The last remnant of this usage in American English may well be a *call* one makes after a death. Obituaries usually contain a notice such as:

> Friends may call from noon to 2 p.m. on Friday at the [funeral home](http://www.kerrbrothersfuneralhome.com/obituaries.php).

The times given constitute *calling* or *visitation* hours. Friends may also *call* at the funeral home and sign a condolence book without *calling* on the family personally.

Clergy may make *hospital calls* collectively, but in reporting a single call on a hospitalized parishioner would most likely say they "visited" someone in the hospital just as anyone else would. More likely would be "calling on" visitors/prospective parishioners.

Contributing to the demise of this usage — even beyond the telephone — is the expression "pay a call on someone," which subsumes the use of "call on s.o."

Comment: Interesting, could it be that the association with mournful events influenced its usage on a more colloquial  basis?

Comment: Rituals have a tendency to preserve archaisms, or even archaic languages like Latin or Old Church Slavonic.

Comment: Yes, but what happened to the more colloquial call on (visit) someone?

Comment: Its social context disappeared and the telephone call took care of the rest.

Comment: That makes sense. That should have happened in BrE too, and online dictionaries should probably be updated.

Comment: I know virtually nothing about British death rituals except that DI Barnaby/Morse/Gently stands some distance away at the gravesite. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about the debate. No, it hasn't fallen out of usage, at least by old people. This is both propper American, and British English, it is a formal term which is not recognized by casual types. I like it, and encourage you to use archaic words and phrases as much as you like. I mean sure I guess it's dated but who cares. If you like it, use it.

> call on
>
> Phrasal Verb
>
> 1. Pay a visit to (someone)
>      ‘he's planning to call on Katherine today’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/call_on

Comment: I upvoted you but the prowlers keep downvoting.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you! I'm a bit old fashioned. I like archaic definitions best. Maybe because my main male role model growing up was born in 1900. "I don't give a damn 'bout my bad reputation." -Joan Jett :)

Comment: Jesse, you need to fix your spellin'. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that to "call on or upon" evolved from the practice of leaving calling cards (aka visiting cards or tickets or compliments cards) at people's homes when stopping by for a short visit.

The practice apparently came from France and then moved to England in the 18th century, according to this source: [calling card](https://hobancards.com/calling-cards-and-visiting-cards-brief-history) Here is a useful quote from it:

"Calling cards were an indispensable accessory to fashionable, upper class life in Britain, Europe, and the eastern United States during the 19th and early 20th centuries. Though they started as simple unadorned cards to announce one's arrival, the Victorians took both the cards' designs and rules dictating usage to extravagant heights."

The following blog entry contains a short round-up of the practice and includes a bibliography at the end:[calling, call and calling card](http://englishhistoryauthors.blogspot.com/2013/08/morning-calls-and-formal-visits.html)

Here is more on the practice of calling cards as regards men in particular: [men](https://www.artofmanliness.com/2008/09/07/the-gentlemans-guide-to-the-calling-card/)

And here from Jane Austen's Pride and Prejudice is a juicy quote about "call on":

"And *that* is quite impossible; for he is now in the custody of his friend, and **Mr. Darcy would no more suffer him to call on Jane in such a part of London**! My dear aunt, how could you think of it? Mr. Darcy may perhaps have *heard* of such a place as Gracechurch Street, but he would hardly think a month's ablution enough to cleanse him from its impurities, were he once to enter it; and depend upon it, Mr. Bingley never stirs without him."

And there is Pickwick Papers and quote with "calling on the defendant Pickwick at these apartments": [calling on](https://books.google.com/books?id=RJsEAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=Dickens%20%2B%20%22calling%20on%22&source=bl&ots=dQGlbWmLzF&sig=IWW4muULyDnZ-dX7i8KcpmQCweQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH74SgvP3YAhUSzlMKHWyCAQ4Q6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=Dickens%20%2B%20%22calling%20on%22&f=false)

Nineteenth century literature is rife with this social practice.....I realize this does not exactly pinpoint the expression but it surely locates it within social history.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard someone say "I called on Ken on my way home," yet here I am seeing it taught in Japan for the first time and thinking it's a mistake... This seems incredibly archaic to me as an Australian and don't see why it's being taught. Even if it's not completely dated, it's on it's way out.

Comment: Not according to [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=called+on+John&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalled%20on%20John%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccalled%20on%20John%3B%2Cc0), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/call-on), [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call-on-someone), [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+on) ... nor in my (UK) experience.